# JS not loading + Script errors & Admin panel is not responding - on Mac High Sierra

Tags: macos, magento2, macos-high-sierra

I have been trying to set up Magento on my mac [High Sierra], Tried both V2.2.6 and V2.2.5 with the recommended requisites [PHP 7.1, MySQL 5.7, Apache 2.4]

Every time I set it up:
-the admin panel is not responding properly

-Failed to load JS and script errors on the console. Attaching the errors I see in the latest install [V2.2.5]

[image: Screenshot of the console errors]

I tried the solutions I found - deploying static content, clearing caches et cetera, nothing works

Seeing that the system requirements also suggest Linux distro, I tried setting up in an Ubuntu machine, and it worked fine!

- Will Magento work on mac High Sierra?
- If so, how can I set it up properly

  `sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

  Cache cleared successfully
  File system cleanup:
  /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/generated/code/Amazon
  /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/generated/code/Composer
  /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/generated/code/Dotdigitalgroup
  /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/generated/code/Klarna
  /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/generated/code/Magento
  /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/generated/code/Symfony
  /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/generated/code/Temando
  /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/pub/static/adminhtml
  /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/pub/static/deployed_version.txt
  /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/pub/static/frontend
  /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/var/view_preprocessed/pub
  Updating modules:
  Schema creation/updates:
  Module 'Magento_Store':
  Module 'Magento_Directory':
  Module 'Magento_Eav':
  Module 'Magento_Backend':
  Module 'Magento_Theme':
  Module 'Magento_Customer':
  Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
  Module 'Magento_Indexer':
  Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Config':
  Module 'Magento_Authorization':
  Module 'Magento_Cms':
  Module 'Magento_Rule':
  Module 'Magento_Backup':
  Module 'Magento_Catalog':
  Module 'Magento_Bundle':
  Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':
  Module 'Magento_Quote':
  Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
  Module 'Magento_Security':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Payment':
  Module 'Magento_Cron':
  Module 'Magento_Msrp':
  Module 'Magento_Search':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
  Module 'Magento_Widget':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
  Module 'Magento_Sales':
  Module 'Magento_Checkout':
  Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':
  Module 'Magento_User':
  Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
  Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales':
  Module 'Magento_Contact':
  Module 'Magento_Cookie':
  Module 'Magento_Email':
  Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':
  Module 'Magento_Vault':
  Module 'Magento_Integration':
  Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Deploy':
  Module 'Magento_Developer':
  Module 'Magento_Dhl':
  Module 'Amazon_Core':
  Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
  Module 'Magento_ImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':
  Module 'Magento_Newsletter':
  Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':
  Module 'Magento_Fedex':
  Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':
  Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':
  Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_Ui':
  Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':
  Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Paypal':
  Module 'Magento_InstantPurchase':
  Module 'Magento_Analytics':
  Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':
  Module 'Magento_Marketplace':
  Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':
  Module 'Magento_Multishipping':
  Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':
  Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
  Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':
  Module 'Magento_SalesRule':
  Module 'Magento_PageCache':
  Module 'Magento_Captcha':
  Module 'Klarna_Core':
  Module 'Magento_Persistent':
  Module 'Magento_Reports':
  Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':
  Module 'Amazon_Login':
  Module 'Magento_QuoteAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_ReleaseNotification':
  Module 'Magento_Review':
  Module 'Magento_RequireJs':
  Module 'Magento_SendFriend':
  Module 'Magento_ReviewAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_Robots':
  Module 'Magento_Rss':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':
  Module 'Amazon_Payment':
  Module 'Magento_SalesAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':
  Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':
  Module 'Klarna_Ordermanagement':
  Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
  Module 'Magento_CustomerAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_Shipping':
  Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
  Module 'Magento_Signifyd':
  Module 'Magento_Sitemap':
  Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':
  Module 'Magento_Swagger':
  Module 'Magento_Swatches':
  Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':
  Module 'Magento_Tax':
  Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':
  Module 'Klarna_Kp':
  Module 'Magento_Translation':
  Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':
  Module 'Magento_Ups':
  Module 'Magento_SampleData':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_Usps':
  Module 'Magento_Variable':
  Module 'Magento_Braintree':
  Module 'Magento_Version':
  Module 'Magento_Webapi':
  Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':
  Module 'Magento_Weee':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':
  Module 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email':
  Module 'Magento_WishlistAnalytics':
  Module 'Shopial_Facebook':
  Module 'Temando_Shipping':
  Module 'Vertex_Tax':
  Schema post-updates:
  Module 'Magento_Store':
  Module 'Magento_Directory':
  Module 'Magento_Eav':
  Module 'Magento_Backend':
  Module 'Magento_Theme':
  Module 'Magento_Customer':
  Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
  Module 'Magento_Indexer':
  Running schema recurring...
  Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Config':
  Module 'Magento_Authorization':
  Module 'Magento_Cms':
  Module 'Magento_Rule':
  Module 'Magento_Backup':
  Module 'Magento_Catalog':
  Running schema recurring...
  Module 'Magento_Bundle':
  Running schema recurring...
  Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':
  Module 'Magento_Quote':
  Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
  Module 'Magento_Security':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Payment':
  Module 'Magento_Cron':
  Running schema recurring...
  Module 'Magento_Msrp':
  Module 'Magento_Search':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
  Running schema recurring...
  Module 'Magento_Widget':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
  Running schema recurring...
  Module 'Magento_Sales':
  Module 'Magento_Checkout':
  Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':
  Module 'Magento_User':
  Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
  Running schema recurring...
  Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales':
  Module 'Magento_Contact':
  Module 'Magento_Cookie':
  Module 'Magento_Email':
  Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':
  Module 'Magento_Vault':
  Module 'Magento_Integration':
  Running schema recurring...
  Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Deploy':
  Module 'Magento_Developer':
  Module 'Magento_Dhl':
  Module 'Amazon_Core':
  Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
  Module 'Magento_ImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':
  Module 'Magento_Newsletter':
  Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':
  Module 'Magento_Fedex':
  Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':
  Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':
  Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_Ui':
  Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':
  Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Paypal':
  Module 'Magento_InstantPurchase':
  Module 'Magento_Analytics':
  Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':
  Module 'Magento_Marketplace':
  Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':
  Module 'Magento_Multishipping':
  Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':
  Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
  Running schema recurring...
  Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':
  Module 'Magento_SalesRule':
  Module 'Magento_PageCache':
  Module 'Magento_Captcha':
  Module 'Klarna_Core':
  Module 'Magento_Persistent':
  Module 'Magento_Reports':
  Running schema recurring...
  Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':
  Module 'Amazon_Login':
  Module 'Magento_QuoteAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_ReleaseNotification':
  Module 'Magento_Review':
  Module 'Magento_RequireJs':
  Module 'Magento_SendFriend':
  Module 'Magento_ReviewAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_Robots':
  Module 'Magento_Rss':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':
  Module 'Amazon_Payment':
  Module 'Magento_SalesAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':
  Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':
  Module 'Klarna_Ordermanagement':
  Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
  Module 'Magento_CustomerAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_Shipping':
  Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
  Running schema recurring...
  Module 'Magento_Signifyd':
  Module 'Magento_Sitemap':
  Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':
  Module 'Magento_Swagger':
  Module 'Magento_Swatches':
  Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':
  Module 'Magento_Tax':
  Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':
  Module 'Klarna_Kp':
  Module 'Magento_Translation':
  Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':
  Module 'Magento_Ups':
  Module 'Magento_SampleData':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_Usps':
  Module 'Magento_Variable':
  Module 'Magento_Braintree':
  Module 'Magento_Version':
  Module 'Magento_Webapi':
  Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':
  Module 'Magento_Weee':
  Running schema recurring...
  Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':
  Module 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email':
  Running schema recurring...
  Module 'Magento_WishlistAnalytics':
  Module 'Shopial_Facebook':
  Module 'Temando_Shipping':
  Module 'Vertex_Tax':
  Data install/update:
  Module 'Magento_Store':
  Module 'Magento_Directory':
  Module 'Magento_Eav':
  Module 'Magento_Backend':
  Module 'Magento_Theme':
  Module 'Magento_Customer':
  Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
  Module 'Magento_Indexer':
  Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Config':
  Module 'Magento_Authorization':
  Module 'Magento_Cms':
  Module 'Magento_Rule':
  Module 'Magento_Backup':
  Module 'Magento_Catalog':
  Module 'Magento_Bundle':
  Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':
  Module 'Magento_Quote':
  Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
  Module 'Magento_Security':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Payment':
  Module 'Magento_Cron':
  Module 'Magento_Msrp':
  Module 'Magento_Search':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
  Module 'Magento_Widget':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
  Module 'Magento_Sales':
  Module 'Magento_Checkout':
  Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':
  Module 'Magento_User':
  Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
  Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales':
  Module 'Magento_Contact':
  Module 'Magento_Cookie':
  Module 'Magento_Email':
  Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':
  Module 'Magento_Vault':
  Module 'Magento_Integration':
  Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Deploy':
  Module 'Magento_Developer':
  Module 'Magento_Dhl':
  Module 'Amazon_Core':
  Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
  Module 'Magento_ImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':
  Module 'Magento_Newsletter':
  Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':
  Module 'Magento_Fedex':
  Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':
  Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':
  Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_Ui':
  Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':
  Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Paypal':
  Module 'Magento_InstantPurchase':
  Module 'Magento_Analytics':
  Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':
  Module 'Magento_Marketplace':
  Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':
  Module 'Magento_Multishipping':
  Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':
  Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
  Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':
  Module 'Magento_SalesRule':
  Module 'Magento_PageCache':
  Module 'Magento_Captcha':
  Module 'Klarna_Core':
  Module 'Magento_Persistent':
  Module 'Magento_Reports':
  Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':
  Module 'Amazon_Login':
  Module 'Magento_QuoteAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_ReleaseNotification':
  Module 'Magento_Review':
  Module 'Magento_RequireJs':
  Module 'Magento_SendFriend':
  Module 'Magento_ReviewAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_Robots':
  Module 'Magento_Rss':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':
  Module 'Amazon_Payment':
  Module 'Magento_SalesAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':
  Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':
  Module 'Klarna_Ordermanagement':
  Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
  Module 'Magento_CustomerAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_Shipping':
  Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
  Module 'Magento_Signifyd':
  Module 'Magento_Sitemap':
  Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':
  Module 'Magento_Swagger':
  Module 'Magento_Swatches':
  Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':
  Module 'Magento_Tax':
  Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':
  Module 'Klarna_Kp':
  Module 'Magento_Translation':
  Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':
  Module 'Magento_Ups':
  Module 'Magento_SampleData':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_Usps':
  Module 'Magento_Variable':
  Module 'Magento_Braintree':
  Module 'Magento_Version':
  Module 'Magento_Webapi':
  Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':
  Module 'Magento_Weee':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':
  Module 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email':
  Module 'Magento_WishlistAnalytics':
  Module 'Shopial_Facebook':
  Module 'Temando_Shipping':
  Module 'Vertex_Tax':
  Data post-updates:
  Module 'Magento_Store':
  Module 'Magento_Directory':
  Module 'Magento_Eav':
  Module 'Magento_Backend':
  Module 'Magento_Theme':
  Running data recurring...
  Module 'Magento_Customer':
  Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
  Module 'Magento_Indexer':
  Running data recurring...
  Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Config':
  Module 'Magento_Authorization':
  Module 'Magento_Cms':
  Module 'Magento_Rule':
  Module 'Magento_Backup':
  Module 'Magento_Catalog':
  Module 'Magento_Bundle':
  Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':
  Module 'Magento_Quote':
  Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
  Running data recurring...
  Module 'Magento_Security':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Payment':
  Module 'Magento_Cron':
  Module 'Magento_Msrp':
  Module 'Magento_Search':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
  Module 'Magento_Widget':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
  Module 'Magento_Sales':
  Module 'Magento_Checkout':
  Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':
  Module 'Magento_User':
  Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
  Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales':
  Module 'Magento_Contact':
  Module 'Magento_Cookie':
  Module 'Magento_Email':
  Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':
  Module 'Magento_Vault':
  Module 'Magento_Integration':
  Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Deploy':
  Module 'Magento_Developer':
  Module 'Magento_Dhl':
  Module 'Amazon_Core':
  Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
  Module 'Magento_ImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':
  Module 'Magento_Newsletter':
  Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':
  Module 'Magento_Fedex':
  Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':
  Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':
  Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_Ui':
  Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':
  Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':
  Module 'Magento_Paypal':
  Module 'Magento_InstantPurchase':
  Module 'Magento_Analytics':
  Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':
  Module 'Magento_Marketplace':
  Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':
  Module 'Magento_Multishipping':
  Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':
  Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
  Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':
  Module 'Magento_SalesRule':
  Module 'Magento_PageCache':
  Module 'Magento_Captcha':
  Module 'Klarna_Core':
  Module 'Magento_Persistent':
  Module 'Magento_Reports':
  Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':
  Module 'Amazon_Login':
  Module 'Magento_QuoteAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_ReleaseNotification':
  Module 'Magento_Review':
  Module 'Magento_RequireJs':
  Module 'Magento_SendFriend':
  Module 'Magento_ReviewAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_Robots':
  Module 'Magento_Rss':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':
  Module 'Amazon_Payment':
  Module 'Magento_SalesAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':
  Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':
  Module 'Klarna_Ordermanagement':
  Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
  Module 'Magento_CustomerAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_Shipping':
  Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
  Module 'Magento_Signifyd':
  Module 'Magento_Sitemap':
  Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':
  Module 'Magento_Swagger':
  Module 'Magento_Swatches':
  Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':
  Module 'Magento_Tax':
  Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':
  Module 'Klarna_Kp':
  Module 'Magento_Translation':
  Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':
  Module 'Magento_Ups':
  Module 'Magento_SampleData':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogAnalytics':
  Module 'Magento_Usps':
  Module 'Magento_Variable':
  Module 'Magento_Braintree':
  Module 'Magento_Version':
  Module 'Magento_Webapi':
  Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':
  Module 'Magento_Weee':
  Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':
  Module 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email':
  Module 'Magento_WishlistAnalytics':
  Module 'Shopial_Facebook':
  Module 'Temando_Shipping':
  Module 'Vertex_Tax':
  Nothing to import.`

  ```
  sudo php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile                                 
  Compilation was started.
  Interception cache generation... 7/7 [============================] 100% 1 min 282.0 MiB
  Generated code and dependency injection configuration successfully.
  ```

sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Deploy using quick strategy
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2139/2139           ============================ 100% %  10 secs
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         2110/2110           ============================ 100% %  7 secs
frontend/Magento/luma/en_US             2155/2155           ============================ 100% %  4 secs

Execution time: 28.040190935135

```
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex 
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

sudo php bin/magento c:c 
Cleaned cache types:
config
layout
block_html
collections
reflection
db_ddl
eav
customer_notification
config_integration
config_integration_api
full_page
translate
config_webservice
```

After executing the above, the admin is still not responding properly, and with following console errors:

[image]

pub/static files are there but somehow fails to load

Comment: Well, does the files actually exist? (problem with pub/static ?) ; what happen when you reset the cache? Tell us what each of these commands do: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` ; `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` ; `php bin/magento s:s:d` ; `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` ; `php bin/magento c:c`

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response @nicolallias I have added the answer in the post.

Comment: I would think that's compatible (since https://www.codexpedia.com/magento/magento-2-installation-guide-for-mac-os-high-sierra/ exists but does not indicate the exact version). I never attempted on mac... Did you ran into https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154312/cant-add-php-mcrypt-and-php-intl-extensions-on-mac-os-sierra or some of those kind of errors?

Comment: The codexpedia post had helped me through the installation [Followed the post for first installation], but not much of a help afterwards when these JS errors come up.  I am guessing the earlier versions might have worked. mcrypt and intl got added just fine, so no.

Comment: "I tried setting up in an Ubuntu machine, and it worked fine": are the js scritps loaded on the ubuntu install in a similar fashion? (http://localhost/magento/pub/static/...)

Comment: If it works on another machine, It should related to environment config. Please check my posted answer

Answer (score 1):

Have u check your apache2/ngix setting allow override on .htaccess or not?

Generally it is denied on new setup environment.

Here is a sample reference on apache2 config to allow override .htaccess.

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thank you, @L.C. Echo Chan

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.4 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
    Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
    RewriteEngine On
</Directory>

This is already included in apache2 config. Still doesn't work